# Excel 2007 document form button not working

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a file which works fine on one user account, but not on other. Both users are logging into the same PC.

What happens is that when the file is open and we click on the form button, it should click it, but it just highlights the button. On the other account it does click.

We are using Office 2007 SP3 and Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: Security settings in Office are user dependent. Have you trusted the document in the this user profile, or enable macros, etc?

Comment: I don't know what was causing it but I fix it by remove the microsfto temp files from appdata/local